# KTable with windowing produces wrong type

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a few problems with creating a KTable with a timewindow in Kafka.

I want to create a table that counts the number of ID's in the stream like this.

```
ID (String) |  Count (Long)
    X       |       5
    Y       |       6
    Z       |       7
```

and so forth. I want to able to get the table using the Kafka REST-API, preferably as .json.

Heres my code at the moment:

```
    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

    KStream<String, String> streams = builder.stream(srcTopic);

    KTable<Windowed<String>, Long> numCount = streams
            .flatMapValues(value -> getID(value))
            .groupBy((key, value) -> value)
            .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(windowSizeMs).advanceBy(advanceMs))
            .count(Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("foo"));
```

The problem I'm facing right now is that the table isn't created as a `<String, Long>` but as `<String, String>` instead. Which means that I can't get the correct count number, but instead I'm receiving the correct key but with corrupted counts. I've tried to force it out as a `Long` using `Long.valueOf(value)` without success. I don't know how to proceed from here. Do I need to write the KTable to a new topic? Since I want the table to be queryable using the kafka REST-API I don't think it's needed, am I right? The `Materialized.<String, Long, WindowStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("foo")` should make it queryable as "foo", right?

The KTable creates a `changelog`-topic, is this enough in order to make it queryable? Or do I have to create a new topic for it to write to?

I'm using another KStream to verify the output now.

```
KStream<String, String> streamOut = builder.stream(srcTopic);

streamOut.foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " => " + value));
```

and it outputs:

```
 ID    COUNT
2855 => ~
2857 => �
2859 => �
2861 => V(
2863 => �
2874 => �
2877 => J
2880 => �2
2891 => �=
```

Either way, I don't really want to use a KStream to collect the output, I want to query the KTable. But as mentioned, I don't really understand how the query works..

**Update**

Managed to get it to work with

```
    ReadOnlyWindowStore<String, Long> windowStore =
            kafkaStreams.store("tst", QueryableStoreTypes.windowStore());
        long timeFrom = 0;
        long timeTo = System.currentTimeMillis(); // now (in processing-time)
        WindowStoreIterator<Long> iterator = windowStore.fetch("x", timeFrom, timeTo);
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          KeyValue<Long, Long> next = iterator.next();
          long windowTimestamp = next.key;
          System.out.println(windowTimestamp + ":" + next.value);
        }
```

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output type of `KTable` is `<Windowed<String>,String>` because in Kafka Streams multiple windows are maintained in parallel to allow handling out-of-order data. Thus, it's *not* the case, that there is a single window instance, but many window instances in parallel. (cf. https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#hopping-time-windows)

Keeping "older" windows allow to update them when data arrives late. Note, Kafka Streams semantics is based on event-time.

You can still query the `KTable` -- you only need to know what window you want to query.

**Update**

The JavaDoc describe how to query the table: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/TimeWindowedKStream.java#L94-L101

> ```
> KafkaStreams streams = ... // counting words
> Store queryableStoreName = ... // the queryableStoreName should be the name of the store as defined by the Materialized instance
> ReadOnlyWindowStore<String,Long> localWindowStore = streams.store(queryableStoreName, QueryableStoreTypes.<String, Long>windowStore());
>
> String key = "some-word";
> long fromTime = ...;
> long toTime = ...;
> WindowStoreIterator<Long> countForWordsForWindows = localWindowStore.fetch(key, timeFrom, timeTo); // key must be local (application state is shared over all running Kafka Streams instances)
> ```

Comment: Okay, thanks! I realize now that there of course must be multiple windows for it to work. The problem still exists with it returning a KTable as `<Windowed<String>,String>`. I edited my question with the output I'm receiving now. I don't understand why the characters are as they are, and not just "1" or "3" as they should be.. Am i printing the window instead of the second string?

Comment: It's unclear from your code how you try to query -- I update my answers. Maybe you should consider reading the docs.

Comment: Sorry, i completely forgot to update the question with the actual querying. My bad. Thanks for your help! One more question, do you know there's any easy way to fetch all keys and their values in a WindowStore? It only seems to work with KeyValueStores...

Comment: `WindowedReadOnlyStore` has an `all()` method since 1.1 release (cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-205%3A+Add+all%28%29+and+range%28%29+API+to+ReadOnlyWindowStore)